# Modify table td width

Tags: css, xml, xslt, html-table

I work with XML and XSL.

I want to build up a table using XML and modify the width using XSL.
My table in XML would be :

```
<table>
<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>
<tbody>
<tr><td>.</td><td>.</td><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
<tr><td>.</td><td>.</td><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

So, I would have 4 columns. What is the best way to modify each of the width of the 4 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this is a rather odd questions. Why use xslt to add markup.

This is html you are generating, thus I assume your gona show the results in a browser like manner. Then I would suggest you use plane old css to do the presentation.

To do this, just add a class to your table tag and then add css to style.

Example:

`<table class="MyNewTable">
....
</table>`

and then add a style part (inline or linked to a seperate file)

`<style type="text/css">
    .MyNewTable td {width: 50px;}
</style>`

Comment: Ok, if I do it in your way, how can I say what the width of each column should be? I just knew how to set the width of the whole table...

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. You can use the 'nth-child()' selector to do that. See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp for more info on that. Using the selector you can set the width of any individual column. Example: if you have 7 columns and want to set the 5th column width and background use: `.MyNewTable tr td:nth-child(7n+5) {width: 50px;background-color:red;}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do that in XSLT... But here you go - verbose edittion:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

        <xsl:output method="html"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Table example</title>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        table.outputTable { width : 100%; border : 1px solid green;}
                        table.outputTable  td { border-bottom : 1px solid gray; border-right : 1px solid gray;}
                        .oddRow {background-color : #CCCCFF;}
                        .evenRow {background-color : #FFCCCC;}
                        .col2 { width : 10% }
                        .col3 { width : 33% }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </body>
            </html>

        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="table">
            <xsl:element name="table">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">outputTable</xsl:attribute>
                <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody/tr"/>
                </tbody>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="tr">
         <xsl:element name="tr">
             <xsl:attribute name="class">oddRow</xsl:attribute>
             <xsl:apply-templates />
         </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="tr[position() mod 2 = 0]">
        <xsl:element name="tr">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">evenRow</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="td">
            <xsl:element name="td">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">col<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope it helps